# Search and replace with TAB character in Sublime Text 2

Tags: find-and-replace, sublime-text-2

In Sublime Text 2, I want search and replace by the TAB character.

I tried replacing with `\t` char but it's not working.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use regular expressions by clicking on this button:

[image: sublime]

The regex for a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character is `\t`.

Comment: Thanks works fine. But you don't need use `/` before and after `\t` is enough

Comment: Also, it's possible to insert/paste a symbol of an actual tab(ASCII, 9 or U+0009) into "Replace" field. Couldn't paste here because the StackOverflow replaces these in comments section.

Comment: I am trying to search for a pipe `|` and replace with a tab, when i use regular expression search as shown above, the search seems to match every character - maybe i have to escape the pipe? e.g. search for `\|`?

Comment: It works. Thx for you!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer only give half of the answer to the question

If you want to replace ',' and insert tab:
[image]

But to replace the tab text with real tab you first have to replace tab text with a different character, and then do the tab insert:

Step1/2)
[image]

Step2/2)
[image]